# Sqlite passing database through functions

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to pass my sqlite database through to a function and then through to another one again. Here is my code.

```
//database Name
// Create a handle for database connection, create a pointer to sqlite3
sqlite3 *dataDB;

//I send it through to the function here
// Execute the query for creating table
retval = sqlite3_exec(dataDB,create_students,0,0,0);
```

My prototypes:

```
int readInFiles(sqlite3 ** dataDB);
void addCourse(sqlite3 ** dataDB, struct course,int k);
```

Call from within the `readInFiles` function:

```
addCourse(&dataDB,deg,k);
```

Here is my error:

```
"database.c", line 50: warning: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
      prototype: pointer to pointer to struct sqlite3 {} : "database.h", line 51
```

Comment: Please rollback my edit(s) if I misunderstood the comments in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within `readInFiles`, `dataDB` is of type `sqlite3**` already, so you need to call:

```
addCourse(dataDB,deg,k);
```

Comment: Im trying that at the moment and getting this error "database.c", line 50: warning: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
        prototype: pointer to struct sqlite3 {} : "database.h", line 51
        argument : pointer to pointer to struct sqlite3 {}

Comment: Did you change anything else? The message said the prototype was "sqlite3**", but in this comment it says "sqlite3*".... something's fishy.

Comment: yea it was sqlite* that i must have changed it to at some point thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply pass the pointer itself? The `readInFiles` and `addCourse` functions presumably don't need to write to the pointer, only to the `sqlite3` object.

```
sqlite3 *db;

retval = sqlite3_exec(db, create_students, 0, 0, 0);

int readInFiles(sqlite3 *db);
void addCourse(sqlite3 *db, struct course, int k);

addCourse(db, deg, k);
```

Also, `dataDB` (datadatabase) is kind of redundant :)

Answer (score 0):

you may try addCourse(dataDB, deg, k);
I don't get it,Do  you want to initialize the db in the readInFile?
If you just use db, you can declare like readInFile(sqlite3* dataDB) and addCourse(sqlite* dataDB)